# Laravel 5.5 APK file uploading issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, file-upload

In my project I am working with `apk` file to upload. In my controller I write

```
if ($request->hasFile('app_file')) {
        $apk_file = $request->app_file->store('app_file');
        $app->app_file = $apk_file;
    }
```

Upload works fine. But instead of `.apk` file it store as `.zip` or `.jar` file. Till now I don't use any validation. Where is the actual issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

.zip , .apk and .jar all are compression so your editor or  is assuming it as .zip or .jar. Try to copy that .zip or .jar and install it in mobile and it should work as expected

Answer (score 0):

I used this to save the uploaded file :

```
Storage::disk('public')->putFile('app_files', $request->file('file_path'))
```

But after upload the file with .apk it becomes .jar
I changed it to this :

```
 $file = $request->file('file_path');
                $destinationPath = storage_path('app/public/app_files');
                $fileName = time() . '_' . rand(1111, 9999) . '_' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
                $data["file_path"] = "app_files/" . $fileName;
```